# SQL finding records with the same value in one of the fields

Tags: sql

hey i am trying to Identify those events which start at the same time as one of the co72010 lectures. and I'm not sure how to go about doing this do i have to do an `INNER JOIN` or `GROUP BY`?

```
events

id          modle kind     dow    tod    duration       room
co12004.L01 co12004 L   Wednesday 11:00     1   cr.SMH
co12004.L02 co12004 L   Monday    17:00     1   cr.B13
co12004.T01 co12004 T   Monday  11:00       2   co.G78+G82
co12004.T02 co12004 T   Tuesday 15:00       2   co.B7
co12004.T03 co12004 T   Tuesday 13:00       2   co.G78+G82
```

Comment: I don't see anything that has a co72010 in any of the fields.  There, that was easy.

Comment: haha its not the whole list of records... :P

Comment: The point of stating a value into your question is to help others try to find a way to help you. The information is useless unless you show the community the correct values so that one may best understand what you're saying to avoid such comment as @Siyual who in fact is right.

Comment: In such scenario, it is good to have sample data and the desired result so that one may see what is to be achieved.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `Exists` for this.  Perhaps something like this:

```
Select  E.*
From    Events  E
Where Exists
(
    Select  1
    From    Events  O
    Where   O.dow = E.dow
    And     O.tod = E.tod
    And     O.modle = 'co72010'
)
```

Alternatively, you can use a `Join` as well:

```
Select  E.*
From    Events  E
Join    Events  O   On  O.Dow = E.Dow
                    And O.Tod = E.Tod
Where   O.Modle = 'co72010'
```

Comment: This seems to be bringing back all but the co7210 result?

Comment: @Richard If you also want the `co7210` row, remove the join condition `And O.id <> E.id`

Comment: Ah, wasn't sure if you wanted the co72010 result.  I've updated the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select  E.*
From    event  E
Where Exists
(
    Select  1
    From    event  O
    Where   O.dow = E.dow
    And     O.tod = E.tod
    And     O.modle = 'co72010'
) and E.modle != 'co72010'
```

So that it doesn't show the same module, only the ones that are at the same time as co72010, but not it itself ??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.modle, a.dow, a.tod, b.id, b.modle, b.dow, b.tod
FROM event a JOIN event b on (a.dow=b.dow AND a.tod=b.tod)
WHERE a.modle = 'co72010' AND b.modle != 'co72010'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Providing a little context on why this is the right solution would be helpful.